# unexpected behavior of 'sprintf'

Tags: r

The following code returns an empty character string:

```
sprintf("%s some message", NULL)
# character(0)

# Expected result:
# " some message" or an error
```

Is it a normal behavior? The `sprintf` documentation does not seem to talk about `NULL` arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already reported as bug [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16915), but it is actually the expected behavior.

The documentation `?sprintf` states:

> Zero-length arguments are allowed and will give a zero-length result

[Duncan Murdoch](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16915#c2) explained it:

> This is standard behaviour for functions that take vectors as arguments and treat them in a vectorized way.  If one of the arguments is length zero, the result is length zero.  For example, 1 + NULL is a length zero numeric vector.

So if you want to use `NULL`, stick with `paste`:

```
paste(NULL,"some message")
#[1] " some message"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have read more carefully the documentation.